# X509 signatureValue size

Tags: x509certificate

The question is why `signatureValue` is so big if it is based on hashes?
Suppose Signature Algorithm is `sha256RSA`.
Shouldn't it be smaller according following steps:

1. Calculate SHA256 hash from `tbsCertificate`. Output => 256 bits.
2. Sign 256 bits hash with RSA private key. Output => 256 bits?

But if you see the size of the `signatureValue`, it might have 2048, 4096, [bigger?] bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature size doesn't depend on hashing algorithm used to hash signed data. It depends on key size only.

The RSA signature is based on modular exponentiation, i.e. `sig = m ^ d mod N`, where:

- `m` is message to be signed
- `d` private exponent (its size is `N / 2`, i.e. 1024 bits for RSA 2048).
- `N` modulus
- `sig` signature value

For such a calculation the final result is the remainder of the `m ^ d` result divided by the modulus (roughly, RSA key size). The `m` and `d` are quite large values and when you power one by another, the value will be huge and won't fit even modulus length, this is why last `mod` operation is used. And you can see, there is no term such as "hash". Sometimes (when very small values are used), resulting value size can be less than modulus size. In such cases, signature value is padded to match the modulus length.

From raw signature you can infer RSA key size, but can't infer the hash algorithm embedded in signature, this is why signature contains asymmetric algorithm and hash name, such as `sha256RSA`, otherwise, you will have to store hash algorithm somewhere in message. Since the combination (asymmetric algorithm and hash algorithm) is finite and quite small, it was good enough to assign unique OIDs to such combinations.